# Make tab position fixed on scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like the idea of the  tab of this website:
http://www.usatoday.com/

When scrolling bellow the logo, 
1- The Tab gets fixed.
2- A smaller logo goes into the tab.

Or, you can say, something similar to Google plus tab.
How can I do this.. 
* I am database developer and have just a background in web tech.

Thanks for help.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

On desktop this should not be to hard:

```
var navigationIsFixed = false;
var $navigation = $("#navigation");
var headerHeight = $("#my-header").height() //To find the height of the header element
$("body").on('scroll', function(e)) { //Fires continuously while the user scrolls
    if ($("body").scrollTop >= headerHeight && !navigationIsFixed) {
        $navigation.css({
            position: "fixed",
            left:  0,
            right: 0,
            top:   0
        });
        $("#logo").stop(); //Make sure to stop any possible ongoing animations
        $("#logo").doCoolAnimation();
        navigationIsFixed = true;
    } else if (navigationIsFixed) {
        $navigation.css( {position: "static"} );
        $("#logo").stop();
        $("#logo").doCoolRevertAnimation();
        navigationIsFixed = false;
    }
}
```

On mobile devices it's a tiny byte harder. You will have to separate your header from the rest of the content in two different div's as the body will not respond as one might think to scroll events.

When using this approach, you will then need to bind your scroll event to the content div

```
<div id="header">
    //Your header code, including the navigation
</div>
<div id="main-content-wrapper">
    //Everything else
</div>
```

css:

```
#main-content-wrapper {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; //Enables inertia scroll on webkit mobile browsers
}
```

I hope i helped :)